# Swift_TransportException при отправки письма

Tags: php, sendmail, gmail

При отправки письма возникает:

> Swift_TransportException
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
>   Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a37-v6sm20900929wrc.21 - gsmtp

Проверил настройки sendmail, (логин, пароль). Все правильно, пересобрал конфиг (сделал make).

В аккаунте gmail включил доступ для небезопасных приложений.

Все равно эта ошибка.

Что еще можно проверить?

Answer (score 0):

похоже, что smtp был заблокирован для бесплатных пользователей хостинга.

http://www.hostinger.ph/forum/news-and-announcements/229-email-service-updates-1.html

Comment: Это что реклама?

Answer (score 0):

C:\xampp\php\php.ini `extension=php_openssl.dll`

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

Также не забудьте перезапустить сервер с помощью панели управления XAMMP, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.

Comment: у меня ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: я скинул Установка и настройка Sendmail на Ubuntu можеш посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Установка и настройка Sendmail на Ubuntu
Это должно помочь вам установить Sendmail с базовой конфигурацией на Ubuntu.

Если sendmail не установлен, установите его: `sudo apt-get install sendmail`
Настроить файл `/ etc / hosts: nano / etc / hosts`
Убедитесь, что строка выглядит так: `127.0.0.1 localhost yourhostname`
Запустите конфигурацию Sendmail и ответьте «Y» на все: `sudo sendmailconfig`
Перезапустить `apache sudo service apache2 restart`